# Could not find function allprevious in Tibco Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

Im trying to calculate the running sum for a line chart. 
The custom expression I'm using is

```
sum([cost]) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.X]))
```

However, I get the error message: could not find function AllPrevious

However this error appears only if I pull the data via SQL/Jdbc. If the data origins from an excel sheet everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the query only works for in memory data. In-DB data requires the use of 'then', as row level data is not available.

Hence the following statement needs to be used

```
sum([cost]) then Sum([Value]) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.X]))
```